# How to fix "Call to undefined function App\money_format()"Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I tried to show the price of a product, formatted under the dollar sign.

this is my function presentPrice
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzEVx.png)

this and here I call  presentPrice
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB06w.png)

I use windows. I read that there is no money_format on windows and I tried to solve this problem with numfmt_format_currency but I did not succeed. Can someone help me?

Sorry for bad english.
Thanks.

Comment: `\money_format(...)`?

Comment: `return \money_format('$%i', $this->price/ 100);`?

Comment: I'm trying to suggest specifically putting that leading \ in there to force it to use the global namespace.

Comment: I'm tried but .. "Call to undefined function money_format()"

Comment: I guess you're running this on a Windows server then which means that function in unavailable to you. You will need to find another one to use, or write your own making use of `number_format`.

Comment: @Jonnix I use `number_format` in this syntax        ` return '$' . number_format($this->product['price'], 2, '.', ''); ` But all prices are 0.

Answer (score -1):

```php
function money_format($formato, $valor) { 

    if (setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 0) == 'C') { 

        return number_format($valor, 2); 
    }

    $locale = localeconv(); 

    $regex = '/^'.             // Inicio da Expressao 
             '%'.              // Caractere % 
             '(?:'.            // Inicio das Flags opcionais 
             '\=([\w\040])'.   // Flag =f 
             '|'. 
             '([\^])'.         // Flag ^ 
             '|'. 
             '(\+|\()'.        // Flag + ou ( 
             '|'. 
             '(!)'.            // Flag ! 
             '|'. 
             '(-)'.            // Flag - 
             ')*'.             // Fim das flags opcionais 
             '(?:([\d]+)?)'.   // W  Largura de campos 
             '(?:#([\d]+))?'.  // #n Precisao esquerda 
             '(?:\.([\d]+))?'. // .p Precisao direita 
             '([in%])'.        // Caractere de conversao 
             '$/';             // Fim da Expressao 

    if (!preg_match($regex, $formato, $matches)) { 
        trigger_error('Formato invalido: '.$formato, E_USER_WARNING); 
        return $valor; 
    } 

    $opcoes = array( 
        'preenchimento'   => ($matches[1] !== '') ? $matches[1] : ' ', 
        'nao_agrupar'     => ($matches[2] == '^'), 
        'usar_sinal'      => ($matches[3] == '+'), 
        'usar_parenteses' => ($matches[3] == '('), 
        'ignorar_simbolo' => ($matches[4] == '!'), 
        'alinhamento_esq' => ($matches[5] == '-'), 
        'largura_campo'   => ($matches[6] !== '') ? (int)$matches[6] : 0, 
        'precisao_esq'    => ($matches[7] !== '') ? (int)$matches[7] : false, 
        'precisao_dir'    => ($matches[8] !== '') ? (int)$matches[8] : $locale['int_frac_digits'], 
        'conversao'       => $matches[9] 
    ); 

    if ($opcoes['usar_sinal'] && $locale['n_sign_posn'] == 0) { 
        $locale['n_sign_posn'] = 1; 
    } elseif ($opcoes['usar_parenteses']) { 
        $locale['n_sign_posn'] = 0; 
    } 
    if ($opcoes['precisao_dir']) { 
        $locale['frac_digits'] = $opcoes['precisao_dir']; 
    } 
    if ($opcoes['nao_agrupar']) { 
        $locale['mon_thousands_sep'] = ''; 
    } 

    $tipo_sinal = $valor >= 0 ? 'p' : 'n'; 
    if ($opcoes['ignorar_simbolo']) { 
        $simbolo = ''; 
    } else { 
        $simbolo = $opcoes['conversao'] == 'n' ? $locale['currency_symbol'] 
                                               : $locale['int_curr_symbol']; 
    } 
    $numero = number_format(abs($valor), $locale['frac_digits'], $locale['mon_decimal_point'], $locale['mon_thousands_sep']); 


    $sinal = $valor >= 0 ? $locale['positive_sign'] : $locale['negative_sign']; 
    $simbolo_antes = $locale[$tipo_sinal.'_cs_precedes']; 

    $espaco1 = $locale[$tipo_sinal.'_sep_by_space'] == 1 ? ' ' : ''; 

    $espaco2 = $locale[$tipo_sinal.'_sep_by_space'] == 2 ? ' ' : ''; 

    $formatado = ''; 
    switch ($locale[$tipo_sinal.'_sign_posn']) { 
    case 0: 
        if ($simbolo_antes) { 
            $formatado = '('.$simbolo.$espaco1.$numero.')'; 
        } else { 
            $formatado = '('.$numero.$espaco1.$simbolo.')'; 
        } 
        break; 
    case 1: 
        if ($simbolo_antes) { 
            $formatado = $sinal.$espaco2.$simbolo.$espaco1.$numero; 
        } else { 
            $formatado = $sinal.$numero.$espaco1.$simbolo; 
        } 
        break; 
    case 2: 
        if ($simbolo_antes) { 
            $formatado = $simbolo.$espaco1.$numero.$sinal; 
        } else { 
            $formatado = $numero.$espaco1.$simbolo.$espaco2.$sinal; 
        } 
        break; 
    case 3: 
        if ($simbolo_antes) { 
            $formatado = $sinal.$espaco2.$simbolo.$espaco1.$numero; 
        } else { 
            $formatado = $numero.$espaco1.$sinal.$espaco2.$simbolo; 
        } 
        break; 
    case 4: 
        if ($simbolo_antes) { 
            $formatado = $simbolo.$espaco2.$sinal.$espaco1.$numero; 
        } else { 
            $formatado = $numero.$espaco1.$simbolo.$espaco2.$sinal; 
        } 
        break; 
    } 

    if ($opcoes['largura_campo'] > 0 && strlen($formatado) < $opcoes['largura_campo']) { 
        $alinhamento = $opcoes['alinhamento_esq'] ? STR_PAD_RIGHT : STR_PAD_LEFT; 
        $formatado = str_pad($formatado, $opcoes['largura_campo'], $opcoes['preenchimento'], $alinhamento); 
    } 

    return $formatado; 
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.